Uniqueness of interpolation on principal lattice and center of a triangle
Let $T$ be a triangle in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with vertices $a_1,a_2,a_3 \in \mathbb{R}^2$. Its center is defined by $C(T)=\frac{1}{3}(a_1+a_2+a_3)$. Does the following interpolation problem have a unique solution:
Find $p\in P_3$ such that $p$ assumes the function values and values of its partial derivatives given on the principal lattice $L_1(T)$ and the function value given on $C(T)$.
I have thus far only seen interpolation on principal lattices, where I know the problem to find the interpolation of $p \in P_k$ has a unique solution on the principal lattice $L_k(T)$. Is the above statement true? If yes, how do I go about showing this?

Pardon my ignorance, but $P_3$ and more generally $P_k$, what are those?

Yes. This is the famous cubic Hermite finite element. It has degrees of freedom given exactly like you described. Please refer to Brenner-Scott's book Example 3.2.6.

Thanks for the reference, very insightful and more straightforward than I was expecting.
